# Add new filter criteria in Testlink

Tags: php, testlink

I need to add one more filter criteria to this. How can I do it? If any code change need to be done can guide on this?
[This image shows the filter facility we have with our testlink.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vfH0.jpg)

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I am very new to PHP. I haven't started with anything.

Comment: Start with something than if you stuck! come here we will definitely solve your problem :)